# Select button with jQuery for casperjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to select a button with `casperjs`, but my issue is that the button has changing `IDs`and `classes`. I can only "identify" the button, based on the text of a `span` 2 levels done:

```
<button class="changes-always" id="changes-always-too">
   <div class="changes-always2">
      <span class="changes-always3">Same text</span>
   </div>
</button>
```

With jQuery I can select the `button`, by first selecting the `span`, because it always has the same content.

```
var span = $('span:contains("Same text")');
var button = span.parent().parent() // there is probably a nice way to do this
```

I got jQuery loaded by `casperjs` by including it as `clientScripts`, my issue is how to correctly get it working with the `evaluate(function()` as well as use the variables as selectors with `casperjs` (if that's even possible)

This is how far I got, but then I ran into problems with `object` and `string` issues.

```
casper.then(function() {
  var items = this.evaluate(function () {
        return $('span:contains("Some text")');
  });
  console.log(items);
});
```

Would be great, if someone could point me in the right direction, how to use `jQuery` as a selector and then let `casperjs` use it. Thanks many times in advance!

Comment: Your approach should work. What do you need to do with that button? What is in the way?

Comment: I need to click the button, but don't know how to do it or rather pass it over to casperjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use clickLabel() if the text is unique.

```
casper.clickLabel("Some text");
```

This should work for buttons, too.

Another option and still not with jquery should be getting the id's by text and if there are sometimes the same text, grab them out by the index:

```
...
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var buttonIDs;
// get button ID's with specific text by getElementsAttribute with xPath selector
buttonIDs = casper.getElementsAttribute(x("//button[contains(text(),'Some specific text')]"), 'id');
casper.then(function() {
  casper.echo(buttonIDs);
});
casper.then(function() {
  casper.click("button[id='" + buttonIDs[0] + "']");
});

...
```

Comment: Works, but exactly as you said, only if it's unique. Fails if there are more selector with the same label.

Comment: I updated the answer, added another option. It's still not with jquery, but i think that's optional to solve your problem. ;)